# Saving fonts and colors (delphi)

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-7

My system gives the user to change the color and font of several items on multiple forms.

I need a way to save these fonts and colors. My system uses sql so is there a way to save them there or is there another way to save them.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a second table named users_prefereces with 2 column:
users and preferences.

preferences will be a json string where you save the user preferences. in that way you can have a struct with all the user preferences like a string.
when you get the preference string decode that string and you will have the struct.

user_id the id of the usr

second way:

add a column in the users tables alway with json values.

Answer (score 0):

use binary;
1 = bold, 2 = italic, 4 = underline   Now you have a single integer that can represent multiple states

```
case itm of 
7 : bold, italic, underline
6 : italic, underline
5 : bold, underline
4 : underline
3 : bold, italic
2 : italic
1 : bold
end;
```

You can use this method for almost anything that has states that cannot be expressed as an SQL field.