# How to save a font and its details (colour, size, style) in a SQL database?

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-7

In my application, the user wants to be able to change the font (font, fontstyle, fontcolor) and it need to be there till changed in the future.

So basically when the font and its details is selected, it needs to be saved into SQL. Is the possible, how do i do this, will it be a VARCHAR?

Comment: you asked twice the same question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870256/saving-fonts-and-colors-delphi

Answer (score 0):

Save the font-family name in varchar or text
Save the font size in int
Make Three Columns with int named Regular, Italic, Underline
Put 1 for yes and 0 for No

Retrieve these values and apply as per format when the app starts up, or whenever u need

Comment: How do i convert a Tfont into a Tstring